# What constitutes a minimum baremetal hypervisor and does a open source one exist?

Tags: hypervisor

I know there are a number of full featured hypervisors(type 1) in existence including Xen, KVM and VMWare. I am however curious what constitutes a bare minimum as a bare metal hypervisor and if something that is quite small LOC wise exists for hacking purposes or if something of the sort would be difficult to implement with (unoptimized drivers). Thanks.

Comment: Ask the person/place that has defined 'bare metal hypervisor'.. because some would [say that's a type 1](http://blogs.windriver.com/hermeling/2009/03/what-is-a-baremetal-hypervisor.html).

Comment: Well I am curious if you didn't care too much about features what kind of things you would need to make something like that run. i.e. using stuff like vt-x and vt-d of x86 for example.

Comment: Skipping all the other stuff, "What is a minimal/conceptual Hypervisor implementation, with available source code?" Which is .. off-topic, as it's a resource request.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a paper and source code on the internet for a hypervisor called Nova which claims to contain around 9k lines of code. This is significantly smaller than Xen and combines the notion of a microkernel with a hypervisor.